# An HtmlUnit alternative for android?

Tags: java, android, html, selenium, htmlunit

An alternative that allows me to fill an HTML form that has checkboxes and radiobuttons.

I was creating this android app that asks user input and sends that data to a website with an html form, fills it, submits the form, and returns the following results page.

I already managed to send data to the html form and retrieve the page using the HtmlUnit library in eclipse (I have posted the Java code for that below).

However, when I copied that code to my Android project I found out that Android does not support the HtmlUnit library.

Is there another alternative to HtmlUnit for Android? The alternative should be able to fill in texts, checkboxes, radiobuttons into an Html form and click on the submit button

Html form code:

```
<form method="post" action="https://www.xxxxx.com/cgi-bin/xxxxxx.cgi">


<p><em>Person:</em>
<input size="18" name="name"><br>
<input type="radio" name="login" value="no" checked="">Name <input     type="radio" name="login" value="yes">Username</p>

<p><em>Title:</em>
<input size="18" name="title"></p>

<p><em>Department:</em>
<input size="18" name="department"></p>

<p><em>Groups to Search:</em><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="get_student" value="yes" checked=""> Students<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="get_alum" value="yes" checked=""> Alumni<br>

<input type="checkbox" name="get_staff" value="yes" checked=""> Staff<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="get_faculty" value="yes" checked=""> Faculty</p>

<p><input type="submit" value="Search"></p>
</form>
```

HtmlUnit Java Code:

```
public static String submittingForm() throws Exception {


    final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController()); 

    WebRequest request = new WebRequest(new URL("https://www.xxxxx.com/"));

    // Get the first page
    HtmlPage page1 = webClient.getPage(request);

    System.out.println("PULLING LINKS/ LOADING:");

    // Get the form that we are dealing with and within that form, 
    // find the submit button and the field that we want to change.
    List<HtmlForm> listform = page1.getForms();
    HtmlForm form = listform.get(0);


    HtmlElement Name = page1.getElementByName("name");
    Name.click();
    Name.type("Adonay");
    HtmlElement nameRadio = page1.getFirstByXPath("/html/body//div[@id='wrapper']//div[@id='layout']//div[@id='container']//div[@id='col1']//div[@id='content']//div[@class='directory-search']//form//input[@type='radio' and @value='no']");
    HtmlElement userRadio = page1.getFirstByXPath("/html/body//div[@id='wrapper']//div[@id='layout']//div[@id='container']//div[@id='col1']//div[@id='content']//div[@class='directory-search']//form//input[@type='radio' and @value='yes']");
   /* userRadio.click(); click when username wanted*/
    HtmlElement Title = page1.getElementByName("title");
    Title.click();
    Title.type("");
    HtmlElement Department = page1.getElementByName("department");
    Department.click();
    Department.type("");
    HtmlElement studentBox = page1.getFirstByXPath("/html/body//div[@id='wrapper']//div[@id='layout']//div[@id='container']//div[@id='col1']//div[@id='content']//div[@class='directory-search']//form//input[@type='checkbox' and @name='get_student']");
    studentBox.click();
    //add clicker here
    HtmlElement alumniBox = page1.getFirstByXPath("/html/body//div[@id='wrapper']//div[@id='layout']//div[@id='container']//div[@id='col1']//div[@id='content']//div[@class='directory-search']//form//input[@type='checkbox' and @name='get_alum']");
    alumniBox.click();
    //add clicker here
    HtmlElement staffBox = page1.getFirstByXPath("/html/body//div[@id='wrapper']//div[@id='layout']//div[@id='container']//div[@id='col1']//div[@id='content']//div[@class='directory-search']//form//input[@type='checkbox' and @name='get_staff']");
    staffBox.click();
    //add clicker here
    HtmlElement facultyBox = page1.getFirstByXPath("/html/body//div[@id='wrapper']//div[@id='layout']//div[@id='container']//div[@id='col1']//div[@id='content']//div[@class='directory-search']//form//input[@type='checkbox' and @name='get_faculty']");
    facultyBox.click();
    //add clicker here



    HtmlElement button = page1.getFirstByXPath("/html/body//div[@id='wrapper']//div[@id='layout']//div[@id='container']//div[@id='col1']//div[@id='content']//div[@class='directory-search']//form//input[@type='submit' and @value='Search']");
    // Change the value of the text field

    // Now submit the form by clicking the button and get back the second page.
    HtmlPage page2 = button.click();
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(200);
    return(page2.asXml());
}
```

Comment: `The alternative should be able to fill in texts, checkboxes, radiobuttons into an Html form and click on the submit button`. No. Just use HttpUrlConnection to post the values to the webserver (action url). You do not even have to request the page first as you will know which inputs are on the form.

Comment: Can you please further explain how I could achieve that? Im really new to android (actually programming as a whole - I just took my first CS course). @greenapps

Comment: Actually @greenapps I found a method. Thanks. I thought about what you said and started to dig online. But please try to answer another question that came up. I posted the question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guys I kind of found another method. Since I know the servers address I tried to post the data directly to it using a `DataOutputStream`. Look at the code below:

```
public String searchDirectory() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("https://www.xxxxx.com/xxxxx/xxxxx.cgi");
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setUseCaches(false);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream (con.getOutputStream ());

    String parameters =("name=" + URLEncoder.encode("DATA HERE", "UTF-8"));
    printout.writeBytes (parameters);
    printout.flush ();
    printout.close ();
        /*InputStream inputStream = getApplicationContext().getResources().getAssets().open("White Pages Query Results.html");
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8");
        */
    DataInputStream input = new DataInputStream (con.getInputStream ());
    String line;
    String htmlCode = "";
    while((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
        htmlCode += line;
    }
    return htmlCode;
}
```

As you can see I'm using the names of the Html Elements to access them through java. However as you can see from the html form code in original post the radio buttons have the same name, how can I access/fill them separately without using their names??

Comment: The same name="login" you mean? You do not fill them in both. You fill in nothing. You just send a value for the post parameter login. Like &login=no or &login=yes.

Comment: Your flurry of answers to a series of questions, all advertising this answer, were flagged by the community and removed. We like to make sure that answers directly target the question they are asked on, and to make sure that duplicate questions are marked as such, rather than having duplicate answers in multiple places.

Answer (score 0):

The HtmlUnit folks have started to work on android support. There biggest problem - a class version clash between HtmlUnit (using HttpClient) and and the version of the HttpClient partly integrated inside the android jdk - is now solved.
You can use the distribution from the https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit-android project.

Please try and report any problems.